# Metadata weird changed on sandbox

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, developer

I am currently using mavensmate and sourcetree. For some weird reason all the files for the objects in my repository had changed, most of them are displaying the following change:
[image: object setup changes]
and some of them have missing fields, however this fields are still in the object:
[image: missing fields]

what i dont understand is that I have never modify this objects, it seems like if i where running a newer version of api and suddenly i went backwards?

Comment: The new release hit some orgs, I think, so it's likely that the behavior may have changed. The object permissions missing are newer permissions, and the metadata API only recently started retrieving standard fields. Even though the object doesn't change, changes to the API can, and will, modify those object files between each release. They probably patched older API versions to not return those fields anymore (it was probably a glitch), but if you upgrade to 32.0, you might get them back... Anyways, not an answer, just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I was having a look but I dont know how can I upgrade?